# Filenames and linenumbers for the matches of cat and grep

Tags: unix, grep, cat

My code

```
$  *.php | grep google
```

How can I print the filenames and linenumbers next to each match?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
grep google *.php
```

if you want to span many directories:

```
find . -name \*.php -print0 | xargs -0 grep -n -H google
```

(as explained in comments, -H is useful if xargs comes up with only one remaining file)

Comment: Does the latter code find subdirectories or master directories?

Comment: You need the name because you may not know which file it was - especially if it is bad break that xargs batched things up and had a single file left over.

Comment: Don't forget that you should use -print0 to find and -0 to xargs if you are working in a directory tree that has names with things like embedded whitespace in them.

Comment: @Jonathan & Michael: yes, you are right. I gave the most common case though.
@Masi: subdirectories

Comment: Your first line doesn't print filenames and numbers, the second recurses (which Masi didn't imply). "find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.php -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nH google" would fit the bill.

Comment: Why are you using `-print0` and `xargs -0`? What is the benefit?

Comment: read the previous comments ;-) anyway now I'd simply do find . -name \*.php -exec grep -Hn {} google \;

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't be doing

```
$ *.php | grep
```

That means "run the first PHP program, with the name of the rest wildcarded as parameters, and then run grep on the output".

It should be:

```
$ grep -n -H "google" *.php
```

The `-n` flag tells it to do line numbers, and the `-H` flag tells it to display the filename even if there's only file.  Grep will default to showing the filenames if there are multiple files being searched, but you probably want to make sure the output is consistent regardless of how many matching files there are.

Answer (score 6):

```
grep -RH "google" *.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at ack at http://betterthangrep.com.  The equivalent in ack of what you're trying is:

```
ack google --php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./*.php -exec grep -l 'google' {} \;
```

Comment: That gets the file names, but not the line numbers, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use "man grep" to see other features.

```
for i in $(ls *.php); do  grep -n --with-filename "google" $i; done;
```

Comment: that won't work - the input file is "stdin" when the command is written this way

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs grep -n "searchstring"
```